# converting data to a choice model data structure

Tags: r

I have 10 products listed in `L5num` and I have PANID`s. I am trying to créate a choice model for a multinomial logistic model but I am trying to carry out some data preparation first.

The data looks like the following:

```
        PANID       WEEK L5num
1669  3174607 2008-09-08     9
21356 3362137 2011-08-01     7
15540 3174607 2010-10-04     9
5869  3150938 2009-07-13     3
18401 3174607 2011-02-28     9
10616 3174607 2010-03-22     8
```

I am trying to structure my data such that ID `3174607` chose product 9 etc. I am trying to put the data in the format similar to the following:

```
PANID        Product
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        0
3174607        1
3174607        0
…
Next PANID
```

So that this person bought product 9 out of a choice of 10 products.

Hope this makes sense and any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

Thanks for all the replys, I really appreciate it. I have used all of your answers and they all work. I do have one slight "addition" to my original post. I am hoping to `reshape` my data also. My data has x variables which I did not discuss in the original post.

The data looks like

```
PANID WEEK  L5num X1 X2 X3 X4...
```

Is is possible to apply the methods you have suggested whilst also including the x variables? So the outputs Will be the same as what is currently been suggested but with x variables on the RHS
EDIT 2:

I add the same data with an "x" variable

```
structure(list(PANID = c(3362137L, 3109124L, 3345264L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3169102L, 3322008L, 3174607L, 3800607L, 3368878L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3340018L, 3109124L, 3174607L, 3338756L, 3842948L, 3107920L, 
3174607L, 3369801L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3330266L, 3107920L, 3831099L, 
3837682L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3330266L, 3174607L, 3340299L, 3368936L, 3317974L, 
3174607L, 3322107L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3174607L, 3140616L, 3314419L, 
3174607L, 3369801L, 3174607L, 3375709L, 3361931L, 3174607L, 3160101L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3369801L, 3117754L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3114728L, 3174607L, 3369801L, 3109124L, 3379453L, 3819300L, 
3814491L, 3340547L, 3109124L, 3821025L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3147447L, 
3174607L, 3317578L, 3341081L, 3140418L, 3342014L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3309476L, 3174607L, 3161760L, 
3174607L, 3181172L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3177436L, 3174607L, 
3814533L, 3174607L, 3107334L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3159525L, 3107334L, 3153767L, 3362137L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3308189L, 3174607L, 3300483L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3341206L, 3301655L, 3343145L, 3174607L, 3821710L, 
3348904L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3338764L, 3176552L, 
3372581L, 3822940L, 3340018L, 3338764L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3174607L, 3128389L, 3362137L, 3153239L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3162446L, 3328948L, 3340299L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 
3341206L, 3832469L, 3396135L, 3308577L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3106344L, 3141044L, 
3174607L, 3161760L, 3402438L, 3800607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3339374L, 
3330613L, 3820431L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3362137L, 3174607L, 
3301655L, 3107334L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3817668L, 3174607L, 3114298L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 3174607L, 
3164467L, 3174607L, 3154336L, 3802355L, 3340018L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3402263L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3173872L, 3339366L, 
3837740L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3309096L, 3307926L, 3153767L, 3174607L, 
3107334L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3340018L, 3174607L, 3113837L, 3174607L, 
3340018L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3801282L, 3174607L, 3337006L, 
3174607L, 3330266L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 3188888L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3340018L, 3834762L, 3177436L, 3107334L, 3402263L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3108613L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3340547L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3362137L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 3164467L, 
3819482L, 3379453L, 3160101L, 3801365L, 3340018L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3312850L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3402263L, 3340018L, 3348904L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3350173L, 3301655L, 
3117333L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3147447L, 3107334L, 3812628L, 3837740L, 
3837740L, 3132209L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3308890L, 3310235L, 3361931L, 
3118554L, 3330266L, 3308189L, 3157099L, 3817767L, 3174607L, 3368936L, 
3362137L, 3157099L, 3814533L, 3322404L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3330266L, 3315424L, 3161430L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3802355L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3153767L, 3335679L, 
3174607L, 3831644L, 3313304L, 3339374L, 3160101L, 3822940L, 3141044L, 
3369801L, 3330266L, 3174607L, 3336347L, 3833129L, 3174607L, 3164640L, 
3402263L, 3174607L, 3138511L, 3817767L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3159517L, 
3106344L, 3174607L, 3147447L, 3174607L, 3368936L, 3176552L, 3346551L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3362137L, 3174607L, 3369801L, 
3174607L, 3136226L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3174607L, 
3157099L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3377192L, 3147447L, 
3174607L, 3169771L, 3106344L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3842948L, 3174607L, 
3340018L, 3147447L, 3330266L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3169771L, 
3819482L, 3174607L, 3317511L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 
3340018L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3814533L, 3164467L, 3131490L, 
3375709L, 3164467L, 3335679L, 3339366L, 3164467L, 3139105L, 3174607L, 
3164467L, 3301655L, 3174607L, 3171066L, 3174607L, 3147447L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 3356063L, 3314567L, 3838516L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3341206L, 3339366L, 3356964L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3369801L, 3812750L, 3176552L, 3174607L, 3348904L, 3114298L, 
3174607L, 3835934L, 3325381L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3317974L, 3174607L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3330266L, 3153239L, 3362137L, 3340018L, 3339366L, 
3821710L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3330266L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3340018L, 
3174607L, 3173575L, 3174607L, 3160101L, 3174607L, 3118562L, 3174607L, 
3814491L, 3174607L, 3396788L, 3109124L, 3398057L, 3153767L, 3825836L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3308080L, 3174607L, 3164467L, 3308189L, 3114728L, 
3301655L, 3174607L, 3337337L, 3174607L, 3837211L, 3174607L, 3335810L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3160101L, 3315424L, 3348904L, 
3308080L, 3317974L, 3164467L, 3174607L, 3174607L, 3800607L, 3402263L, 
3174607L, 3174607L, 3106344L, 3174607L, 3815084L, 3308080L), 
    WEEK = structure(c(14788, 14781, 14543, 15005, 14753, 14074, 
    14116, 14599, 14970, 14781, 14928, 14676, 15565, 15033, 14809, 
    14109, 14571, 14207, 14543, 14956, 14767, 14774, 14795, 15635, 
    14193, 15215, 14417, 14802, 14214, 15089, 14690, 14592, 14487, 
    14935, 15537, 14823, 15152, 15264, 14417, 14774, 14193, 14424, 
    15467, 14340, 15565, 13878, 15068, 15593, 15047, 14312, 14032, 
    14669, 14578, 14739, 15131, 15481, 14298, 14487, 15103, 15124, 
    15012, 15012, 14935, 14928, 15194, 15208, 14697, 15131, 14984, 
    14403, 14347, 15033, 14571, 13941, 14690, 15173, 15194, 14382, 
    14060, 14774, 14403, 14676, 14319, 14837, 14921, 14452, 14487, 
    15432, 14676, 14466, 14830, 14585, 14711, 14837, 15110, 14011, 
    14767, 14795, 14949, 14942, 15033, 14445, 14970, 15033, 14963, 
    14781, 14690, 14172, 14452, 14760, 14816, 14431, 14774, 15103, 
    14536, 14550, 14704, 14879, 15495, 14697, 15145, 14515, 15215, 
    14515, 15089, 14739, 14445, 15047, 15236, 15376, 15201, 15131, 
    14949, 14550, 14578, 15082, 14872, 14375, 15124, 14690, 15600, 
    14368, 15432, 14116, 14893, 14851, 14060, 14809, 14620, 15054, 
    15460, 15572, 13990, 15320, 14746, 14760, 14739, 15089, 14830, 
    15089, 15033, 14942, 14165, 14655, 14053, 14676, 14046, 14816, 
    14060, 14774, 14165, 14844, 15124, 15005, 14480, 15257, 14592, 
    14522, 14501, 14340, 14830, 14081, 14340, 15250, 14753, 14417, 
    14837, 14690, 15236, 15047, 15047, 15117, 14711, 15460, 15131, 
    15411, 14725, 14410, 14515, 14669, 14809, 15509, 14557, 14837, 
    15026, 14382, 14228, 14431, 15236, 14760, 14466, 14697, 15201, 
    14445, 14445, 14767, 14606, 14928, 14193, 15579, 15068, 14165, 
    14529, 15089, 14865, 15110, 14816, 14704, 14690, 15586, 14837, 
    14319, 14697, 14690, 14991, 13983, 15523, 13906, 14200, 15327, 
    14956, 14774, 14676, 14417, 15159, 14942, 15110, 14949, 14739, 
    15341, 14578, 14655, 14823, 14851, 15397, 15579, 13955, 15145, 
    14221, 15418, 15537, 14697, 14389, 14928, 15040, 14851, 13927, 
    14389, 14893, 14396, 15278, 14333, 13885, 14305, 14928, 14767, 
    15075, 15054, 14690, 15033, 14081, 15145, 15565, 14123, 14410, 
    13899, 15131, 14830, 14207, 14949, 15180, 15614, 14515, 15369, 
    15201, 15278, 14760, 14655, 14424, 15026, 14144, 15516, 14935, 
    14858, 14480, 14571, 14942, 14102, 14242, 14536, 14753, 14088, 
    15292, 14410, 14445, 14963, 14298, 15250, 14473, 14501, 14935, 
    14599, 15264, 14767, 15124, 13941, 14179, 14977, 14529, 14837, 
    14067, 14459, 14718, 14788, 14445, 14102, 15313, 14725, 14319, 
    14004, 14571, 14928, 14501, 14676, 15432, 15439, 15061, 14459, 
    14151, 14410, 15047, 14172, 14662, 14816, 14963, 15271, 14704, 
    14816, 14816, 14865, 15061, 14445, 15215, 14879, 14480, 14347, 
    14396, 14396, 14956, 13983, 14746, 14788, 14837, 14501, 14739, 
    14487, 13892, 14606, 14809, 14802, 14879, 13983, 14438, 14739, 
    14669, 14403, 15250, 14774, 15257, 15306, 14739, 15131, 14396, 
    14137, 14844, 15033, 15299, 14494, 14963, 14368, 15411, 14270, 
    14606, 15404, 14081, 14830, 14515, 14116, 14529, 14445, 15089, 
    14683, 15054, 14480, 15425, 15467, 14564, 15250, 14277, 15271, 
    15551, 15509, 15467, 14641, 14711, 14375, 15572, 15488, 15124, 
    14914, 15341, 14641, 14662, 14179, 14410, 15460, 14466, 14683, 
    14130, 14578, 15152, 14963, 13955, 14984, 14809, 14312, 14144, 
    14830, 14123, 14851, 14837, 14564, 15047, 15614, 14739, 14571, 
    14424, 13962, 14802, 14816, 14949, 14410, 14592, 15593, 15005, 
    14641, 14389, 14760, 14039, 14515, 15369, 15054, 15152, 14515, 
    14165, 14032, 15117, 15138, 14984, 13934, 15005, 14963, 15096, 
    14795, 14473, 14228, 15061, 14410, 15152, 14683, 14452, 14459, 
    15138, 15425, 14452, 14571, 15334, 14403, 14816, 14452), class = "Date"), 
    L5num = c(7, 3, 7, 9, 8, 9, 2, 9, 6, 2, 8, 9, 6, 3, 8, 2, 
    6, 6, 9, 2, 8, 8, 10, 6, 7, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 10, 
    9, 6, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9, 4, 9, 1, 7, 9, 9, 9, 4, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
    9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 3, 10, 6, 6, 7, 3, 5, 9, 9, 
    6, 9, 1, 2, 7, 2, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 
    4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 1, 7, 10, 7, 8, 9, 9, 
    8, 2, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 3, 4, 7, 9, 7, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 3, 
    4, 6, 6, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 1, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 7, 6, 
    8, 6, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 3, 10, 9, 7, 6, 
    6, 9, 9, 2, 7, 1, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 4, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8, 3, 8, 
    8, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9, 4, 9, 1, 2, 6, 9, 9, 8, 6, 9, 9, 9, 2, 
    7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 4, 10, 9, 7, 9, 4, 6, 9, 2, 9, 6, 9, 9, 8, 
    4, 8, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 7, 7, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
    6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 10, 7, 4, 6, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 8, 1, 6, 7, 9, 9, 5, 10, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 
    6, 10, 7, 7, 9, 9, 4, 9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 10, 6, 9, 10, 7, 9, 
    10, 7, 8, 9, 8, 10, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 3, 9, 8, 9, 9, 10, 
    7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 9, 10, 9, 10, 4, 9, 4, 5, 9, 2, 7, 
    9, 9, 9, 3, 8, 6, 9, 6, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 
    8, 8, 9, 4, 8, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 10, 6, 9, 3, 10, 9, 9, 6, 
    9, 6, 6, 1, 9, 8, 9, 3, 10, 8, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 8, 9, 9, 
    10, 4, 4, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 9, 4, 4, 9, 6, 9, 6, 8, 9, 9, 
    9, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9, 9, 9, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7, 7, 3, 9, 10, 4, 
    9, 6, 2, 9, 6, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 10, 7, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 
    9, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 9, 6, 8, 5, 8, 5, 3, 6, 10, 7, 9, 9, 2, 
    9, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9, 10, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 1, 10, 2, 
    7, 4, 9, 8, 6, 6, 9, 9, 3, 9, 1, 2), Family.Size = c(2L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(13036L, 12834L, 8179L, 17887L, 
11867L, 1036L, 1541L, 9145L, 17275L, 12897L, 16092L, 10428L, 
24672L, 18295L, 13566L, 1454L, 8757L, 2361L, 8106L, 16966L, 12331L, 
12587L, 13236L, 25163L, 2311L, 21600L, 5418L, 13442L, 2482L, 
19924L, 10710L, 8999L, 7010L, 16277L, 24453L, 14022L, 21067L, 
22195L, 5502L, 12573L, 2288L, 5604L, 23753L, 3936L, 24638L, 17L, 
19433L, 24874L, 18797L, 3601L, 731L, 10239L, 8776L, 11645L, 20797L, 
23951L, 3323L, 7019L, 20090L, 20535L, 18087L, 18058L, 16363L, 
16227L, 21366L, 21523L, 10931L, 20839L, 17567L, 5003L, 4147L, 
18394L, 8676L, 305L, 10690L, 21231L, 21397L, 4546L, 962L, 12683L, 
5052L, 10406L, 3620L, 14374L, 15971L, 6406L, 6999L, 23429L, 10349L, 
6652L, 14117L, 8948L, 11088L, 14528L, 20269L, 638L, 12357L, 13066L, 
16764L, 16591L, 18383L, 6102L, 17188L, 18414L, 16997L, 12821L, 
10597L, 2122L, 6308L, 12210L, 13760L, 5748L, 12782L, 20081L, 
8016L, 8248L, 11025L, 15327L, 24064L, 10911L, 20996L, 7692L, 
21597L, 7745L, 19813L, 11663L, 6159L, 18819L, 21814L, 23107L, 
21478L, 20845L, 16815L, 8336L, 8823L, 19690L, 15281L, 4449L, 
20591L, 10605L, 24922L, 4318L, 23481L, 1493L, 15628L, 14853L, 
946L, 13659L, 9496L, 18990L, 23672L, 24721L, 527L, 22688L, 11805L, 
12111L, 11691L, 19908L, 14248L, 19843L, 18365L, 16503L, 2017L, 
9918L, 874L, 10440L, 827L, 13863L, 967L, 12732L, 1994L, 14707L, 
20612L, 18043L, 6827L, 22131L, 9024L, 7828L, 7343L, 3950L, 14063L, 
1110L, 3899L, 22080L, 11907L, 5305L, 14319L, 10637L, 21792L, 
18845L, 18881L, 20431L, 11169L, 23688L, 20748L, 23301L, 11473L, 
5283L, 7652L, 10263L, 13525L, 24187L, 8407L, 14415L, 18256L, 
4568L, 2703L, 5858L, 21788L, 12242L, 6657L, 10913L, 21440L, 6220L, 
6013L, 12410L, 9253L, 16220L, 2251L, 24751L, 19446L, 2042L, 7895L, 
19871L, 15067L, 20311L, 13733L, 11064L, 10699L, 24831L, 14384L, 
3668L, 10907L, 10721L, 17641L, 505L, 24340L, 153L, 2317L, 22759L, 
16837L, 12497L, 10439L, 5441L, 21121L, 16457L, 20295L, 16668L, 
11591L, 22842L, 8801L, 9931L, 14046L, 14792L, 23242L, 24765L, 
411L, 21002L, 2562L, 23375L, 24459L, 10865L, 4812L, 16165L, 18617L, 
14819L, 236L, 4821L, 15606L, 4896L, 22410L, 3859L, 56L, 3491L, 
16158L, 12457L, 19609L, 18955L, 10644L, 18450L, 1106L, 20967L, 
24685L, 1632L, 5300L, 121L, 20697L, 14178L, 2431L, 16808L, 21305L, 
24995L, 7735L, 23059L, 21441L, 22418L, 12201L, 9991L, 5666L, 
18193L, 1839L, 24240L, 16265L, 15011L, 6818L, 8733L, 16602L, 
1343L, 2798L, 8000L, 11989L, 1187L, 22516L, 5246L, 6099L, 17059L, 
3358L, 21960L, 6742L, 7378L, 16424L, 9194L, 22187L, 12320L, 20656L, 
295L, 2166L, 17417L, 7872L, 14536L, 1010L, 6495L, 11245L, 13047L, 
6193L, 1336L, 22650L, 11430L, 3642L, 565L, 8633L, 16090L, 7322L, 
10444L, 23485L, 23523L, 19310L, 6512L, 1868L, 5248L, 18802L, 
2123L, 10045L, 13852L, 17041L, 22224L, 10978L, 13730L, 13770L, 
15062L, 19198L, 6026L, 21553L, 15423L, 6839L, 4018L, 4978L, 4870L, 
16916L, 498L, 11749L, 12968L, 14404L, 7440L, 11613L, 7059L, 81L, 
9306L, 13621L, 13317L, 15421L, 500L, 5987L, 11600L, 10284L, 5096L, 
22032L, 12712L, 22102L, 22614L, 11572L, 20781L, 4902L, 1771L, 
14573L, 18304L, 22586L, 7154L, 17097L, 4391L, 23305L, 3066L, 
9292L, 23270L, 1126L, 14250L, 7625L, 1530L, 7855L, 6085L, 19921L, 
10537L, 19031L, 6887L, 23405L, 23776L, 8630L, 22017L, 3156L, 
22252L, 24574L, 24172L, 23783L, 9755L, 11180L, 4520L, 24732L, 
23985L, 20552L, 15878L, 22799L, 9769L, 10146L, 2155L, 5204L, 
23678L, 6665L, 10509L, 1670L, 8797L, 21056L, 16989L, 407L, 17565L, 
13666L, 3603L, 1795L, 14158L, 1616L, 14834L, 14521L, 8595L, 18860L, 
25015L, 11646L, 8649L, 5601L, 420L, 13286L, 13864L, 16643L, 5285L, 
8979L, 24880L, 17801L, 9825L, 4817L, 12218L, 771L, 7662L, 23046L, 
19119L, 21016L, 7726L, 2004L, 728L, 20379L, 20958L, 17549L, 283L, 
17822L, 17009L, 20008L, 13209L, 6725L, 2685L, 19311L, 5273L, 
21046L, 10471L, 6348L, 6464L, 20940L, 23410L, 6335L, 8679L, 22772L, 
5089L, 13868L, 6397L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `Data` is the input data.frame then:

```
library(mlogit)
mlogit.data(Data, choice = "L5num", shape = "wide")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `tabulate` and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
n <- dat[, uniqueN(L5num)] # 10
out <- dat[, .(Product = tabulate(L5num, n)), by = PANID]
out #                                    ^ total number of products
```

---

For illustration I am using a small example.

Input:

```
(dt <- as.data.table(head(unique(dat[, c("PANID", "L5num")]), 2)))
#     PANID L5num
#1: 3801365     4
#2: 3174607     9
```

Output:

```
out <- dt[, .(Product = tabulate(L5num, 10)), by = PANID]
out
#      PANID Product
# 1: 3801365       0
# 2: 3801365       0
# 3: 3801365       0
# 4: 3801365       1
# 5: 3801365       0
# 6: 3801365       0
# 7: 3801365       0
# 8: 3801365       0
# 9: 3801365       0
#10: 3801365       0
#11: 3174607       0
#12: 3174607       0
#13: 3174607       0
#14: 3174607       0
#15: 3174607       0
#16: 3174607       0
#17: 3174607       0
#18: 3174607       0
#19: 3174607       1
#20: 3174607       0
```

---

**EDIT**

If we need to apply this operation to more than one column we need to do

```
n <- dat[, uniqueN(L5num)] # 10
cols <- setdiff(names(dat), c("PANID", "WEEK")) # don't apply function to "WEEK" column
out <- dat[, lapply(.SD, tabulate, nbins = n), by = PANID, .SDcols = cols]
```

**EDIT 2**

I am not sure what the expected output is but if you want to extend all "x" columns you might use a join.

Input:

```
(dt <- as.data.table(head(unique(dat), 2)))
#     PANID       WEEK L5num Family.Size
#1: 3362137 2010-06-28     7           2
#2: 3109124 2010-06-21     3           3
```

Now the the calculation and merge with `dt` on "PANID"

```
out <- dt[dt[, .(Product = tabulate(L5num, n)), by = PANID], on = "PANID"
          ][, L5num := NULL] # removes column L5num
out
#      PANID       WEEK Family.Size Product
# 1: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 2: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 3: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 4: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 5: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 6: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 7: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       1
# 8: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
# 9: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
#10: 3362137 2010-06-28           2       0
#11: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#12: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#13: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       1
#14: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#15: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#16: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#17: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#18: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#19: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
#20: 3109124 2010-06-21           3       0
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also use the following base R approach:

```
n <- 10 # Number of products
data.frame(PANID = rep(df$PANID, each = n), 
           Product = replace(numeric(n * nrow(df)), 0:(nrow(df) - 1) * n + df$L5num, 1))
#        PANID Product
# 1    3801365       0
# 2    3801365       0
# 3    3801365       0
# 4    3801365       1
# 5    3801365       0
...
```

We start with the `Product` column as a zero vector given by `numeric(n * nrow(df))` and then add ones in the needed places (`0:(nrow(df) - 1) * n + df$L5num`) with `replace`.

---

If there are some more variables, we may do

```
data.frame(PANID = rep(df$PANID, each = n), 
           Product = replace(numeric(n * nrow(df)), 0:(nrow(df) - 1) * n + df$L5num, 1),
           df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = n), -1:-3, drop = FALSE])
#           PANID Product Family.Size
# 13036   3362137       0           2
# 13036.1 3362137       0           2
# 13036.2 3362137       0           2
```

where the extra variables will be repeated `n` times for each `PANID`. If there is more than one variable, `drop = FALSE` is not needed.

Comment: @user8959427, if I understood your update correctly, I added another line on what to do to preserve extra variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dummyVars`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-81/topics/dummyVars) package -

```
library(caret)
df$L5num <- as.factor(df$L5num)
dmy <- dummyVars("PANID ~ L5num", data=df)
d <- as.data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = df))
d$PANID <- rownames(d)
d1 <- melt(d,id.vars="PANID")
d1<-d1[order(d1$PANID),]
d1$variable <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df %>%
 do(data.frame(PANID = rep(.$PANID, each = 10), #Replicating "PANID" and "L5num" 10x
               L5num = rep(.$L5num, each = 10))) %>%
 mutate(temp = gl(length(PANID)/10, 10)) %>% #For all "PANID" values generating an ID
 group_by(temp) %>% #Grouping by ID
 mutate(rowid = seq_along(temp)) %>% #Sequencing around ID to create a row ID
 mutate(Product = ifelse(rowid == L5num, 1, 0)) %>% #Checking whether the row ID is equal to "L5num"
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rowid,-L5num,-temp) #Removing the redundant variables

     PANID Product
     <int>   <dbl>
 1 3174607      0.
 2 3174607      0.
 3 3174607      0.
 4 3174607      0.
 5 3174607      0.
 6 3174607      0.
 7 3174607      0.
 8 3174607      0.
 9 3174607      1.
10 3174607      0.
11 3362137      0.
12 3362137      0.
13 3362137      0.
14 3362137      0.
15 3362137      0.
16 3362137      0.
17 3362137      1.
18 3362137      0.
19 3362137      0.
20 3362137      0.
```